# How to run appium on headless Linux

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, headless, appium, xvfb

How do I run tests in headless fashion  (for web testing I use XVFB for running browser tests in headless on Jenkins), so how it will work for automation on AVD/Device

I am trying to run a mobile web test using appium on Centos 6 headless linux but I am keep getting this error:

```
"info: [CHROMEDRIVER STDERR] No protocol specified

info: Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error      
occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"**unknown error: an X display is required for    
keycode onversions, consider using Xvfb\n**  (Session info: chrome=webview)\n  
(Driver info:chromedriver=2.9.248316,platform=Linux 2.6.32042stab088.4x86_64)"}, 
"sessionId":"8563fbe5972f3ba87673c7a082d49d22"}POST /wd/hub/session/8563fbe5972f3ba87673c7a082d49d22/element/0.06753459526225924-1/value 500 1927ms - 395b

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/8563fbe5972f3ba87673c7a082d49d22

debug: Request received with params: {}

info: Shutting down appium session..."
```

It opens up the chrome browser and navigates to the given url. After that it tries **sendKeys** to the username field and then it fails.

Answer (score 4):

We just had this issue and solved it by wrapping the appium server call in a call to xvfb:

```
xvfb-run appium --session-override --command-timeout=0 &
```

(or whatever you appium server settings are)

xvfb-run will then handle the headless server setup and shutdown for you.